# How to get "Event" object's specific element by javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

### Summary

I implemented select box in `Vue.js`/`Nuxt.js` application by `Vuetify.js`.
I added `@change` event to get selected value.

```html
<v-select
  v-model="selectedStartTime"
  :items="startTime"
  item-text="text"
  item-value="value"
  @change="onChangeEndTime"
/>
```

```js
onChangeEndTime (e : Event) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Developer Console shows object value which is selected.
I want to know how to get its specific element value `hour` and `minute` in onChangeEndTime function.

[image: ```]

### what I tried

1. `console.log(e.target)` returned `undefined`.
2. `console.log(e.hour)` returns the exact value. but it shows error message `Property 'hour' does not exist on type 'Event'.Vetur(2339)`
   .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-select`'s `change`-event argument is the selected value itself (not an `Event` object), which is the object containing `hour` and `minute`.

One solution is to change the type of `e` from `Event` to `{ hour: number, minute: number }`:

```js
onChangeEndTime (e : { hour: number, minute: number }) {
  console.log(e.hour) // ✅ e.hour exists
}
```